# How does java primitives work? , short(short+ int)?

Tags: java

I tried executing the below code :

```
public class Test5 {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    short x = 0;
    int i = 123456;


    x = (short) (x + i);
    System.out.println(x);
}

}
```

How is the output "-7616"? how does integer and short work when type casted to short?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add an int and a short, the resut is an int, which is 4 bytes.

But when you cast it to a short, you're making a short from the last two bytes of the int.

`123456`'s bytes are `0x0 0x1 0xe2 0x40`, so you're making a short from `0xe2 0x40`.

The first bit of `0xe2` being a 1, the resulting short is negative.

You can play with this short program to see what happens :

```
int i = 123456; // <== change the value
System.out.format("Bytes of %d: ", i);
byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(i).array();
for (byte b : bytes) {
   System.out.format("0x%x ", b);
}
System.out.format("\nlast two bytes : %d*256 + %d = %d\n", bytes[2], bytes[3], (short)(bytes[2]*256 + bytes[3]));
```

Output :

```
Bytes of 123456: 0x0 0x1 0xe2 0x40 
Last two bytes : -30*256 + 64 = -7616
```

Answer (score 3):

Long version:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

Short version:
Java takes the 16 least significant bits of the int, and puts them into the short in the same order.

Answer (score 1):

`short` is 2-byte integer. And java types cannot be "unsigned" as in C. So, max value is 32767. (Short.MAX_VALUE).

As you can see you tried to put bigger value to this variable:

```
123456
 32767
```

The binary representation of such value is as negative value you posted. BTW the same happens in C.

Answer (score 1):

This is something called narrowing primitive conversions. You are trying to convert `int` to `short`.

It may be too technical but try to understand [Java Language Specification, section 5.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3).

Answer (score 0):

Maximum value of `short` datatype is 32,767. And here you have added 123456 with 0. 123456 is bigger than max value of `short`, so it is truncated.

Comment: @UsmanSaleem: no, truncated. The last 16 bits are kept, and the first 16 bits are discarded.

Answer (score 0):

Explicit casting. when you cast a Java int to a short, you will get silent truncation.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `x + i` is `int`. This int contains a value that is bigger than the max value of short. When you cast it to a short, the 16 last bits of the 32 bits int are taken to make the short, and these 16 last bits happen to represent a negative short value.

The Java Language Specification says:

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause the sign of the resulting value to differ from the sign of the input value.

Answer (score 0):

Or look at this code, run it. It ought to be easier to figure it out with an example.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        short v = 32767;
        System.out.println(v);
        v += 1;
        System.out.println(v);
        v += 1;
        System.out.println(v);

        System.out.println();

        v = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 123; i++) {
            int intVal = i * 1000;
            v = (short) intVal;
            System.out.println("intVal[" + intVal + "] shortVal[" + v + "]");
        }
    }
}
```

The output...

```
32767
-32768
-32767

intVal[0] shortVal[0]
intVal[1000] shortVal[1000]
intVal[2000] shortVal[2000]
intVal[3000] shortVal[3000]
intVal[4000] shortVal[4000]
intVal[5000] shortVal[5000]
intVal[6000] shortVal[6000]
intVal[7000] shortVal[7000]
intVal[8000] shortVal[8000]
intVal[9000] shortVal[9000]
intVal[10000] shortVal[10000]
intVal[11000] shortVal[11000]
intVal[12000] shortVal[12000]
intVal[13000] shortVal[13000]
intVal[14000] shortVal[14000]
intVal[15000] shortVal[15000]
intVal[16000] shortVal[16000]
intVal[17000] shortVal[17000]
intVal[18000] shortVal[18000]
intVal[19000] shortVal[19000]
intVal[20000] shortVal[20000]
intVal[21000] shortVal[21000]
intVal[22000] shortVal[22000]
intVal[23000] shortVal[23000]
intVal[24000] shortVal[24000]
intVal[25000] shortVal[25000]
intVal[26000] shortVal[26000]
intVal[27000] shortVal[27000]
intVal[28000] shortVal[28000]
intVal[29000] shortVal[29000]
intVal[30000] shortVal[30000]
intVal[31000] shortVal[31000]
intVal[32000] shortVal[32000]
intVal[33000] shortVal[-32536]
intVal[34000] shortVal[-31536]
intVal[35000] shortVal[-30536]
intVal[36000] shortVal[-29536]
intVal[37000] shortVal[-28536]
intVal[38000] shortVal[-27536]
intVal[39000] shortVal[-26536]
intVal[40000] shortVal[-25536]
intVal[41000] shortVal[-24536]
intVal[42000] shortVal[-23536]
intVal[43000] shortVal[-22536]
intVal[44000] shortVal[-21536]
intVal[45000] shortVal[-20536]
intVal[46000] shortVal[-19536]
intVal[47000] shortVal[-18536]
intVal[48000] shortVal[-17536]
intVal[49000] shortVal[-16536]
intVal[50000] shortVal[-15536]
intVal[51000] shortVal[-14536]
intVal[52000] shortVal[-13536]
intVal[53000] shortVal[-12536]
intVal[54000] shortVal[-11536]
intVal[55000] shortVal[-10536]
intVal[56000] shortVal[-9536]
intVal[57000] shortVal[-8536]
intVal[58000] shortVal[-7536]
intVal[59000] shortVal[-6536]
intVal[60000] shortVal[-5536]
intVal[61000] shortVal[-4536]
intVal[62000] shortVal[-3536]
intVal[63000] shortVal[-2536]
intVal[64000] shortVal[-1536]
intVal[65000] shortVal[-536]
intVal[66000] shortVal[464]
intVal[67000] shortVal[1464]
intVal[68000] shortVal[2464]
intVal[69000] shortVal[3464]
intVal[70000] shortVal[4464]
intVal[71000] shortVal[5464]
intVal[72000] shortVal[6464]
intVal[73000] shortVal[7464]
intVal[74000] shortVal[8464]
intVal[75000] shortVal[9464]
intVal[76000] shortVal[10464]
intVal[77000] shortVal[11464]
intVal[78000] shortVal[12464]
intVal[79000] shortVal[13464]
intVal[80000] shortVal[14464]
intVal[81000] shortVal[15464]
intVal[82000] shortVal[16464]
intVal[83000] shortVal[17464]
intVal[84000] shortVal[18464]
intVal[85000] shortVal[19464]
intVal[86000] shortVal[20464]
intVal[87000] shortVal[21464]
intVal[88000] shortVal[22464]
intVal[89000] shortVal[23464]
intVal[90000] shortVal[24464]
intVal[91000] shortVal[25464]
intVal[92000] shortVal[26464]
intVal[93000] shortVal[27464]
intVal[94000] shortVal[28464]
intVal[95000] shortVal[29464]
intVal[96000] shortVal[30464]
intVal[97000] shortVal[31464]
intVal[98000] shortVal[32464]
intVal[99000] shortVal[-32072]
intVal[100000] shortVal[-31072]
intVal[101000] shortVal[-30072]
intVal[102000] shortVal[-29072]
intVal[103000] shortVal[-28072]
intVal[104000] shortVal[-27072]
intVal[105000] shortVal[-26072]
intVal[106000] shortVal[-25072]
intVal[107000] shortVal[-24072]
intVal[108000] shortVal[-23072]
intVal[109000] shortVal[-22072]
intVal[110000] shortVal[-21072]
intVal[111000] shortVal[-20072]
intVal[112000] shortVal[-19072]
intVal[113000] shortVal[-18072]
intVal[114000] shortVal[-17072]
intVal[115000] shortVal[-16072]
intVal[116000] shortVal[-15072]
intVal[117000] shortVal[-14072]
intVal[118000] shortVal[-13072]
intVal[119000] shortVal[-12072]
intVal[120000] shortVal[-11072]
intVal[121000] shortVal[-10072]
intVal[122000] shortVal[-9072]
```